# How to execute a .NET console-application in memory using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

From my C# program, I am trying to execute a byte[] containing another .NET executable (a C# console-application) directly from memory and without touching disk.

I am aware that there are similar questions posted here and also some good articles about how to do it like this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory

However, they all run into the same problem, they work BUT only for executing Windows Forms applications in memory, but when I try to execute Console-Applications it doesn't work. Example:

```
byte[] FileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\MyTestProgram.exe");   // just for testing purposes

Assembly a = Assembly.Load(FileBytes);
MethodInfo m = a.EntryPoint;
m.Invoke(a.CreateInstance(m.Name), null);
```

And when 'MyTestProgram.exe' is a Windows Form, it executes perfectly. But when 'MyTestProgram.exe' is a Console Application, it returns the following error:

"Unhandled exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch"

Please note that the console application doesn't receives any arguments, so this is strange...

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: as usual `Main` method has one `string[] param` parameter. You dont send it in `Invoke` call, but you should.

Comment: thanks for the ultra quick help, but how can I make the Invoke call to take into account the string[] parameter of the Main method of the console-application?

Comment: @samsam: you can read the documentation for `Invoke` for a start. Not that hard, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main method is static, you don't need to pass `Invoke` an instance. You have to call it like this:

```
 var parameters = m.GetParameters().Length == 0 ? null : new[] { new string[0] };
 m.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

This code handles both `Main()` and `Main(string[] args)` variations.

Comment: !!! Amazing it now worked like a charm. You really did some great magic in there :D Thanks a looot !!